# Modifying numbers in table with certain max and min value

Tags: lua

I have a basic table containing random numbers between 32 and 512. I want to be able to increase and decrease the value of each number by 10 unless the smallest number in the table is = 32 or the largest is = 512.

I'm using a clamp method to restrict my numbers to given values, and everythng works, however all the numbers will be reduced to the lowest instead of the function pausing if the lowest number in the table is at 32. So they'll all go to 32 or 512, instead of stopping wherever they are when one of the numbers hits 32 or 512.

```
if math.min(table.unpack(sequences.c1Sequence.data)) >= 32 and math.max(table.unpack(sequences.c1Sequence.data)) <= 512 then
  for i, v in ipairs(sequences.c1Sequence.data) do
    sequences.c1Sequence.data[i] = util.clamp(v + (10*d), 32, 512)
  end
end
```

To clarify "d" is either a 1 or -1 each time the function is called, so i = i +/- 10 depending upon what goes in.

The clamp function is:

```
util.clamp = function(n, min, max)
  return math.min(max,(math.max(n,min)))
end
```

And the table is simply:

```
data = {33, 122, 97, 64, 222, 314, 90, 39, 63, 44, 312, 502, 34, 409, 111, 212}
```

Or any other random range of number.

I'd expect that when any number in the range = 32 or 512 then the function wont do anything and the numbers will get left alone. Instead they all (if the function keeps receiving -1 many times) go to 32 or (if the function keeps getting +1) go to 512. The randomness isn't kept.

Cheers :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood your problem correctly, try the following:

```
local unpack = unpack or table.unpack

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

function min(...)                       --return minimum of all elements
  local ans = select(1,...)
  if type(ans) == 'table' then ans = min(unpack(ans)) end
  for _,n in ipairs { select(2,...) } do
    if type(n) == 'table' then n = min(unpack(n)) end
    if n < ans then ans = n end
  end
  return ans
end

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

function max(...)                       --return maximum of all elements
  local ans = select(1,...)
  if type(ans) == 'table' then ans = max(unpack(ans)) end
  for _,n in ipairs { select(2,...) } do
    if type(n) == 'table' then n = max(unpack(n)) end
    if n > ans then ans = n end
  end
  return ans
end

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

function pt(t)
  print('{'..table.concat(t,', ')..'}')
end

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

function adjust(t,val)
  if min(t)+val < 32 or max(t)+val > 512 then return t end
  local ans = {}
  for _,x in ipairs(t) do
    ans[#ans+1] = x+val
  end
  return ans
end

--==============================================================================
-- Test
--==============================================================================

data = {33, 122, 97, 64, 222, 314, 90, 39, 63, 44, 312, 502, 34, 409, 111, 212}

pt(data)                      --original data

data=adjust(data,-1)
pt(data)

data=adjust(data,-1)
pt(data)

data=adjust(data,10)
pt(data)

data=adjust(data,1)
pt(data)

data=adjust(data,1)
pt(data)
```

Comment: This is working, it's causing errors elsewhere in my code I'm unable to track down but I can see how this works. I'll keep hunting for the other errors. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you just need to change comparisons to `~=`

```
data = {33, 122, 97, 64, 222, 314, 90, 39, 63, 44, 312, 502, 34, 409, 111, 212}

clamp = function(n, min, max)
  return math.min(max,(math.max(n,min)))
end

while (true)do
    if math.min(table.unpack(data)) ~= 32 and math.max(table.unpack(data)) ~= 512 then
      for i, v in ipairs(data) do
          data[i] = clamp(v + (10*-1), 32, 512) 
      end
    else
        print(table.unpack(data))
        break
    end
end
```

-1 Output

> 32    112 87  54  212 304 80  32  53  34  302 492 32  399 101 202

+1 Output

> 43    132 107 74  232 324 100 49  73  54  322 512 44  419 121 222

Comment: This kinda works but still results in values levelling out over time, so they'll all end up at 1 or 512.